# Is it possible to run Eclipse Portable on Linux using Wine?

Tags: java, linux, windows, eclipse, wine

I'm trying to sync an Eclipse installation between Linux and Windows, so I've installed EclipsePortable on Windows and moved the EclipsePortable installation to Linux Mint. Is it possible to run Eclipse Portable on Linux using Wine? I installed Eclipse Portable on Dropbox from Windows, and then tried to run it using Wine on Linux, but it simply displayed the loading screen and then crashed.

Comment: I'm not sure which JRE is being used by Eclipse on Linux, but this might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764168/portable-jre-on-linux-possible

Comment: Eclipse has itself distribution for linux. Why do you want to use Wine to run a Windows version?

Comment: It's not necessary to do that.  Eclipse is Java based, so installing Java and running Eclipse natively would probably be an easier approach.

Comment: @Kane I'm trying to synchronize the Eclipse installation between Windows and Linux. Is it possible to get a singe Eclipse installation to work properly on both platforms (including the workspaces)?

Comment: @Makoto What is the recommended way to sync an Eclipse installation between Windows and Linux, then? (I want to synchronize the entire Eclipse installation, instead of just a few workspaces.)

Comment: I can't see a motivation *to* synchronize any IDE between Windows and Linux.  If you wanted the benefit of your code being on two platforms at once, a VCS such as Git (hint:  [GitHub](http://www.github.com) is free!) would be *far* more ideal.

Comment: @Makoto I mainly want all of the installed plugins to be synchronized between Linux and and Windows (so that I won't need to install them manually on each platform).

Comment: Maybe this is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176602/how-to-keep-an-eclipse-installation-in-sync-between-multiple-platforms-with-drop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though Eclipse is Java based application, however some of its platform module depend on native code, such as native launchers and SWT.

That's why Eclipse provides different distribution for different hosts.

Technically you still can have a portable Eclipse. You can install host specific plug-ins into one Eclipse instance, but it does not have a UI to do it. When launching those Eclipse in a host(AKA linux), Eclipse will not load the plug-ins for Windows.

In a word it could be done, but it is very difficult for normal users. So far I don't know a guide for it.

Just two my cents.

Comment: I decided to use NetBeans instead of Eclipse, since you can move NetBeans projects between operating system platforms without running into any compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, yes you can.

To me the important key is to set the correct architecture, and a custom Wine folder:

```
export WINEPREFIX=~/.wine-myapp
export WINEARCH=win32
```

Then you should install your Java jvm, for example:

```
wine jre-8u181-windows-i586.exe
```

In my case I could install Oracle Java v8 for 32 bits but never could do with same version for 64 bits. To do this I use a windows build of OpenJDK or copied an installation on a Windows machine to my Wine instalation.

You can launch your eclipse with something like:

```
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine-myapp2 WINEARCH=win32 ~/.wine-myapp//drive_c/Program\ Files/eclipse/eclipse.exe
```

More minor details are in my blog post at http://olea.org/diario/2018/07/27/EPF_Composer_in_Linux.html

My only trouble is the GUI widgets looks very ugly.